# How to insert(Add) JSON data in MySql database through Postman or Rest API Framework using Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have started coding in Python using Django and MySql recently.So, I am facing issue in simple inserting data(JSON format) in a table in MySql database.I have tried few things which I am mentioning below.But it did not work.And I am using the following - Python, Django Framework, MySql Database, mysqlclient connector, Rest API Framework, Postman. Please help me out with suggestions.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import fetchdata
from .serializers import fetchdataSerializers
from rest_framework import status,response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.http import HttpResponse

@api_view(['GET','POST'])

def index(request):

 if request.method=='POST':

    try:
        _json = request.json
        _name = _json['name']
        _email = _json['email']
        _password = _json['pwd']
        sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name,user_email,user_password) 
        VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
        data = (_name, _email, _password,)
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        conn.commit()
        resp = jsonify('User added successfully!')
        serializer=fetchdataSerializers(data=request.data)

         if serializer.is_valid():

          serializer.save()

  return resp
  return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You are doing stuff that Django already does for you. Please read about Django's ORM: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/  and follow some Django tutorials to get more grip of the framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support...I have checked the documentation link provided by you...but I am confused about few things...first is where will I write this part of the code .......""  >>> p = Person(name="Fred Flintstone", shirt_size="L")
>>> p.save()
>>> p.shirt_size
'L'
>>> p.get_shirt_size_display()
'Large '""..................as I am using VS ...so I wrote it in terminal...but it's not working...AND second thing is...Isn't it possible to post data from POSTMAN?@Juho Rutila

Comment: Are you using the django shell? python manage.py shell

Comment: No, I am using "python manage.py runserver"......but i have also checked using "python manage.py shell".....then too it is giving error...the error is....""  In [1]:  p = importdata(first_name = "jj")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-98b08ca14697> in <module>
----> 1 p = importdata(first_name = "jj")

NameError: name 'importdata' is not defined  ""......  @Juho Rutila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fixtures folder in your app and place the Json file in it.
The Json file might be something like this category.json

```
[
    {
      "model": "category",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "name": "person",
        "created_at": "2019-05-06T09:27:51.386383",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-06T09:27:51.386383"
      }
    },

  ]
```

Run `python manage.py loadata category.json`. Depending on how you plan to implement this, you can run this command after your migration.
Check the [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/) to understand more

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying...I have tried this, but an error is coming. The error says....""  in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc...
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\Rounak-\Python_Projects\blog_p_root\importdata\fixtures\importdata.json': "".......Can you suggest anything please?? @Anthony Ugwu

Comment: I think it has to do with the fixture you created, make sure there are no discrepancies between your fixture and the database schema

Comment: I created a folder in my app called " fixtures "...The app name is "importdata"...inside the fixtures folder I created a json file named "importdata.json"...Now this file contains ...""" [{
      "model": "importdata",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "first_name": "jj",
        "email": "jj", }}, {*same as previous array*}}] """"...and in my model.py the class name is "" importdata"...and in the database the table migrated has the name..."" importdata_importdata"""...So, this is the details...can you please help me out by pointing out my mistake...????? @Antony Ugwu